# Filter tx_news in front end -Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news

I have a site with tx_news. I need to show all news in front end and filter the news category and date wise. Is there any typoscript setting is available to do it ? How can do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datemenu plugin and categorymenu plugin to filter any list view.

Comment: Can I filter with date and category simultaneously.If possible how can implement that???

Comment: Without testing it but you need to change the templates to change the `<f:link.action />` ViewHelper and add `addQueryString="1"` which will let you keep the arguments set by the 2nd plugin